# Difficult scrolling on mobile devices due to transition/zoom at hover

Tags: css, hover, zooming, transition

I am using a Wordpress theme (Modern Agency, a subtheme of Total). Images of portfolio items zoom, and an icon appears when you hover on them. This also applies to mobile devices, but this is making scrolling difficult: I find myself dragging my finger up and down the screen multiple times in order to scroll, because my mobile browser (iOS iPhone SE) seems to stick to the portfolio item, as opposed to scrolling.

you can find the website [here:](http://www.monosphere.nl)

I have tried to customize the stylesheet, but I cannot find a way to disable the zoom on images.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
.overlay-plus-hover, .overlay-plus-hover:hover, portfolio-entry-media-link, portfolio-entry-media-link:hover, portfolio-entry-img {
transition: none!important;
zoom: 0!important;
}

.wpex-image-hover,.wpex-image-hover:hover, .grow img:hover {
    transition: none!important;
    zoom: 0!important;
}
```

I want to disable the transition on mobile devices in order to allow smooth and normal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Set a media query for mobile screen sizes and set the `transform` attribute to `none` on the `.wpex-image-hover.grow:hover img` class.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .wpex-image-hover.grow:hover img {
        -ms-transform: none;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        -o-transform: none;
        -moz-transform: none;
        transform: none;
     }
 }
```